# How set actuator properties while the game is running?

Tags: game-engine

When I call `bpy.data.objects['Enemy'].game.actuators['<name>'].target = bpy.data.objects['XX']` the value is only updated after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to quit  game and then hitting <kbd>P</kbd> to start the game again.

How can I update the target in real time,  without the need to stop and start the game again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bpy module does not work in the game engine, use the bge functions instead.

For instance:

```
objectList = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects
bge.logic.getCurrentController().actuators['<name>'].target = objectList['XX']
```

More information can be found on the [bge.logic](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bge.logic.html) and [bge.types](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bge.types.html) pages of the blender python api.

Comment: It did not work. Unable to place the actuator seek.